# Picture of the Week no longer requires a funky aspect ratio

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is really an announcement.  Thanks to work from @Jin and I believe, @balpha, next week's contest will no longer be restricting the picture of the week to an 'odd' aspect ratio.  You will be free to use a 'normal' ratio (or if you like the old ratio then that).

That said, there will be two simple restrictions:

- It must still be in landscape orientation.  Portrait style simply wouldn't look correct.
- The image must be sized to 210 px high and *no wider* than 375.

**So entries will no longer have to be cropped in some odd format to compete.**

Comment: Thanks for the update, rfusca!

Comment: YAY! That is great news!

Comment: and there was much rejoicing!

Comment: In other words, does this mean the height *must be* ***exactly*** *210 px*, while the width can be anything from 1 to 375 px?

Comment: @koiyu 'it must still be in landscape orientation' - Height must be exactly 210 and width can be anything from 211 to 375.

Answer (score 6):

Damn! Have you any IDEA how long that Lightroom custom export workflow took me?!

Seriously, great news. :)

Comment: Well, just to validate your effort, we'll change it back...

Comment: Hehe - that's better! ;)